# make many mysql command in one connection in c# visual studio & unknown column in where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, database-connection

I have mySql database contains ID, projectName, companyName, projectNum, .. etc
I need to create Combobox that display projectName (project name isn't unique)
when I try to execute this the following error appears:
**"Unknown column 'proj2' in where clause"**
even though when I try to print this value it prints successfully in my code.
so I changed to display ID in Combobox and works well 
now I need if I choose one ID to fill some fields (projectName, companyName, projectNum) then display values in other Combobox (e.g Combobox2) it has item number which is not unique and it
depend on projectName field.
I try to make one connection and two connection but both of them didn't work.
nothing appears in Combobox2
when I try to choose ID from first Combobox the same error appears:
**"Unknown column 'proj2' in where clause"**
I don't know if should I change the design of the database.
again I should mention that project name, company name, project number may be repeated in more than 50 records.
below is the code
first function to fill the first Combobox:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               // String getQuery = "Select projectName From ubc.BOQ_Table Group By projectName";
                String getQuery = "Select ID From ubc.BOQ_Table";

                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(getQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("ID"));

                    }
                }
               reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

second function to fill fields depend on choosing ID:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try

        {

        //get vaalue of selected project
        selectedProject = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            String selectQuery = "Select * From ubc.BOQ_Table where ID=" + selectedProject;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                projectNameText.Text = reader.GetString("projectName");
                projectName = projectNameText.Text;
                companyNameText.Text = reader.GetString("companyName");
                projectNumber.Text = reader.GetInt32("projectNumber").ToString();

                reader.Close();
            }
                command.CommandText = "Select itemNum From ubc.BOQ_Table where projectName=" + projectName;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString("itemNum"));

                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, maybe this also cases the parsing problems. You need to tell us which line of your code causes the error, what the variable values are and war the layout of the tables is.

Comment: @eckes when executing the query that depends on the project name.                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Because the string needs quotes round it to be a valid SQL string. Otherwise it is interpreted as a column name. Use parameters instead of string concatenation and you will solve a lot of other problems as well as this one (not least SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You don't quote the projectName value, so if it contains something you would get the mentioned complaint (and other more serious problems, don't just quote it, use bind parameters)

Comment: I can't put quotes around it because it is variable not constat, what do you mean by "Use parameters instead of string concatenation" how should I implement that?

Comment: After seeing the sql command, I didn't see any 'proj2' in your code. Therefore, I suggest that you could check where is the word in your code or database.

Comment: @Sarah You should not use it (as explained because SQL injection and missing database optimizations) but quoting would look like `command.CommandText  = "select ... where projectName=\"" + projectName + "/"";` or `$"select ... projectName=\"{projectName}\"";`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is causing the problem:

```
command.CommandText = "Select itemNum From ubc.BOQ_Table where projectName=" + projectName;
```

As commenters have mentioned, concatenating strings is causing both the syntax error and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The solution is to use "parameterized queries" by putting the variable in a `MySqlParameter` object.

```cs
command.CommandText = "Select itemNum From ubc.BOQ_Table where projectName=@projectName;";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectName", projectName);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // ...
```

(You may find some people saying "don't use `AddWithValue`", but that's an objection that applies just to `SqlCommand`; there's no good reason to avoid using it with `MySqlCommand`.)